# Bot Framework deployment with BitBucket "Could not locate the assembly 'Microsoft.Bit.Builder' "

Tags: git, azure, bitbucket, continuous-deployment, botframework

I'm trying to set up continuous deployment for my my bot on azure with BitBucket. Now I get the following error from the log: (this is just a part of it)

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk.
```

When deploying out of Visual Studio to azure WebApp directly it works. Is there a way to include these assemblys with Bitbucket or Git? Or will SCM work with Team Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to commit the dll file.

If you installed the nuget package correctly, it should be Under : [YOURPROJECTPATH]\packages\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.1.0.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.dll

Bitbucket checkin may have excluded it from your commit.